# Python: Внесение списка в список JSON

Tags: python, json

Имею такой `json`

```
{
    "chats_contex": [
        {
            "60": [
                {
                    "can_use_admins": "True",
                    "kick_on_link": "False"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Как добавить в `chats_contex` новый список (название не имеет значение), чтобы получилось так:

```
{
    "chats_contex": [
        {
            "60": [
                {
                    "can_use_admins": True,
                    "kick_on_link": False
                }
            ],
            "example": [
                {
                    "can_use_admins": True,
                    "kick_on_link": False
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Прошу ответить на вопрос с кодом. Заранее спасибо!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фигурные скобки - это словари, квадратные скобки - это списки. К словарям обращаемся по ключу, к спискам - по номеру элемента. Таким образом, получается:

```
data = {
    "chats_contex": [
        {
            "60": [
                {
                    "can_use_admins": "True",
                    "kick_on_link": "False"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

data["chats_contex"][0]["example"] = \
            [
                {
                    "can_use_admins": True,
                    "kick_on_link": False
                }
            ]
```

Comment: как записать это в `json`?

Comment: Если в переменную с тем, что у вас в начале написано, то тут у меня она `data` называется и так в неё и вносится. Если в файл, то через `json.dump`